# How to manage a organization chart according to employee role using google orgChart?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am creating an organization chart according to the employees role (super admin, admin, user), and my sample code is :

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.lang.*" %>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
    data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

    <%      
    Connection conn;
    int l;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appdb", "root", "root");
    }catch(SQLException e) {
        out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage() + "<br/>");
        while((e = e.getNextException()) != null)
            out.println(e.getMessage() + "<br/>");
        throw new UnavailableException(this, "Cannot connect with the specified database.");
    }

    String employe;
    String manager;
    String user_role;
    String title;
    try
    {
        ResultSet rs;
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();            
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employee cu JOIN  department de on de.id = cu.id ");
            while (rs.next())
            {
                employe = rs.getString("user_first_name") +" "+ rs.getString("user_last_name"); 
                manager = rs.getString("man_first_name") +" "+ rs.getString("man_last_name");
                user_role = rs.getString("cu.user_role");
                title = rs.getString("cu.title");
                if(user_role.equals("super_admin")){
                if(manager.equals("null null")){
          %>
                data.addRows([[{v:'<%=employe%>',f:'<%=employe%><br><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Role(<%=user_role%>)</div><BR><div style="color:green">Title : <%=title%></div>'}, '','<%=user_role%>']]);
          <% }else{ %>
                data.addRows([[{v:'<%=employe%>',f:'<%=employe%><br><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Role(<%=user_role%>)</div><BR><div style="color:green">Title : <%=title%></div>'}, '<%=manager%>','<%=user_role%>']]);
          <%} }else if(user_role.equals("admin")){
              if(manager.equals("null null")){
          %>
                data.addRows([[{v:'<%=employe%>',f:'<%=employe%><br><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Role(<%=user_role%>)</div><BR><div style="color:green">Title : <%=title%></div>'}, '','<%=user_role%>']]);
          <% }else{ %>
                data.addRows([[{v:'<%=employe%>',f:'<%=employe%><br><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Role(<%=user_role%>)</div><BR><div style="color:green">Title : <%=title%></div>'}, '<%=manager%>','<%=user_role%>']]);
          <%} }else if(user_role.equals("user")){
              if(manager.equals("null null")){
                  %>
                        data.addRows([[{v:'<%=employe%>',f:'<%=employe%><br><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Role(<%=user_role%>)</div><BR><div style="color:green">Title : <%=title%></div>'}, '','<%=user_role%>']]);
                  <% }else{ %>
                        data.addRows([[{v:'<%=employe%>',f:'<%=employe%><br><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Role(<%=user_role%>)</div><BR><div style="color:green">Title : <%=title%></div>'}, '<%=manager%>','<%=user_role%>']]);
                  <%} }
          %>
          <%
            }
    }catch(SQLException e) {
                e.getMessage();           
    }finally {   // Clean up resources, close the connection.
                if(conn != null)
                {
                    try { conn.close(); }
                    catch (Exception ignored) {}
                }
            }
     %>


    // Create the chart.
    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
    data.setRowProperty(2, 'selectedStyle', 'background-color:#00FF00');
    chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
  }


</script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output : 
[and this is the output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTYYR.png)

but what I actually want even though if a users who does not work under any admin or super admin still he displayed on the bottom of next hierarchy but in my case it is displaying in the top and the same thing is happening with the Admin.
If anybody know the solution of this problem then pleas answer.